# I made a Node group in the Geometry nodes but it does not appear in the templates

Tags: geometry-nodes, asset-browser

[image]

[image]

I have the file saved in the asset library, but it does not appear whenever I try to add it in other projects

Comment: You need to access the node group from the asset browser, node templates are a different feature from an add-on

Comment: Look in the Group submenu, not the Templates submenu, I think that should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your node groups as presets, you would have to save them in a separate file and use the "Node Presets" add-on. However, this is a bit buggy in the current version (v3.1) and you will need to modify it a bit.

You can find out exactly how to do this in the description in this post: [How can I use custom node groups as node templates (Blender 3.1)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260853)